Is it suspicious to write about research with no accompanying letter from a PI for PhD admissions?
I am beginning my applications for PhD programs and am currently writing my statement of purpose (research statement). In it, I spend a bit detailing some work I did in a lab during my second year of undergrad. I found the research pretty interesting, and I feel like it is important to include, as its one of two research experiences I have (and relevant to the programs I'm applying to). But I've become concerned - is it suspicious to not include a letter of recommendation from that PI? I didn't plan on asking them because I barely ever got to know them, as they weren't really around during my time there.
Does it look bad to spend a paragraph of my statement of purpose discussing research in Prof. X's lab, with no corresponding recommendation letter from Prof. X?

You should ask Prof. X.
There is no downside here for you. If they say no, then you’re where you are now. If they accept, you’ll have a correspondingly stronger application. They will likely ask your direct supervisor to write the letter, and the professor will edit and sign.
As for how suspicious it would be, put yourself in the committee’s place. Unless your other letters are very strong, or this research experience rather tangential, it will be obvious that you deliberately didn’t get a letter from this advisor. So of course they will wonder why, and they may be hesitant to take your claims at face value. So: not a disaster, but potentially not as strong as it could be.
